# Check two array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, arrayobject

In the following javascript arrray of objects i want to check if every question id in array two found in array one

```
arrayOne=[{"question":"100","response":"aaaa"},
             {"question":"200","response":"aaaa"}]  

arrayTwo=[{"question":"100","output":true},
             {"question":"200","output":true}]
```

examples

if arrayTwo

```
 arrayTwo=[{"question":"100","output":true}]
```

return false

if arrayTwo

```
    arrayTwo=[{"question":"100","output":true},
             {"question":"200","output":true}]  

return true.
```

How to make function to check the two arrays?

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: How to make function to check the two arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to do this, and it will return `true/false` as result.

```js
var arrayOne = [{
  "question": "100",
  "response": "aaaa"
}, {
  "question": "200",
  "response": "aaaa"
}]

var arrayTwo = [{
  "question": "100",
  "output": true
}, {
  "question": "200",
  "output": true
}]

var result = arrayTwo.every(function(e) {
  return arrayOne.find(function(a) {
    return a.question == e.question;
  })
})

console.log(result)
```